# Problem with loading php_pdo_sqlite.dll and php_sqlite3.dll in php.ini

Tags: php, sqlite, dll, ini

I've downloaded `PHP v8.2.2` manually, without `Apache`

I see `php_pdo_sqlite.dll` and `php_sqlite3.dll` in the `M:\Programs\PHP v8.2.2\ext\`, but when I uncomment these lines in `php.ini`:

```ini
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3
```

or when I manually add these lines instead:

```ini
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

I get these warnings on serving `index.php` using `php -S localhost:8888`:

```
[Thu Feb  2 00:31:14 2023] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Thu Feb  2 00:31:14 2023] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: C:\php\ext\sqlite3 (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_sqlite3.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: C:\php\ext\sqlite3 (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_sqlite3.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
[Thu Feb  2 00:31:14 2023] PHP 8.2.2 Development Server (http://localhost:8888) started
```

I know, the error occurs because php tries to find `dll` files in `C:\php\ext\` path, but that directory doesn't exist!

The `PHP v8.2.2` have installed in `M:\Progarms\PHP v8.2.2\`, not in `C:\php\`

How can I change this default path?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have sqlite3 PHP library working (but allso ssh or ldap) you'll have to add your PHP home directory to the PATH so that apache will find libsqlite3.dll or libsasl.dll (or any lib it need in order to make work php_.dll).